# Which version of ionic should we use

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

We currently have a web app based on AnjularJS 1.4. Now we need to develop mobile apps for our product. We think ionic to be a good framework for us since it's Angular based.

The team has no experience on ionic framework. Now the question is which version of ionic should we use? How to convert one AngularJS 1.4 we app into ionic mobile apps and maximize code reuse? Ionic 2 seems to have better performance and other benefits. Is it possible to make ionic 2 and AngularJS 1.4 coexists in the same code base and reuse current code?

Comment: I don't think there's a straight forward way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to do it. Ionic 2 is based on Angular 2, and comes with many significant performance, usability, and feature improvements.

Ionic 1 at a very high-level is essentially just a wrapper & directive/component library for AngularJS 1.x. Ionic 2 is built  to utilize all the benefits of Angular 2+.

In short, everything must be upgraded in order to get the benefits of Ionic 2. So, If everything you have is working, and performance isn't sluggish, there really is no reason to to choose Ionic 2, you can use Ionic 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to port your code to Angular 2 in order to run with Ionic 2 because Ionic 2 builds upon AngularJs 2.

It takes Angular 2 and adds additional features, like different routing, styles, etc.